# Android: Why would an event fail to post and what should you do if it doesn't?

Tags: android

Androids event posting functions* return a boolean which tells you if they were successfully posted to the handler's thread's message queue or not. What is the proper response to a failure to post an event? Posting again until it works seems like a bad idea. Sleeping and posting again also seems like a bad idea. Is it even necessary to test for this in the general case?

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() { void run(){doStuff}}

    if(!h.post(r){
      //What Should go here????
    }
```

[* post, postDelayed, postAtTime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states, the `post` operation may return false if the looper that handles the message queue is exiting.

That is, if it returns false whatever you have posted won't be processed. So by checking for false you may take action if you need.

But generally you don't, so if it's not important for you to process that last `post`, then you may ignore the check.

Answer (score 0):

alternately you can just keep a local boolean or something as a stubb for later and ignore it for now in `onStop()`and `onDestroy ()` and `onPause()`